# Uploading excel files

Tags: angular

I am very new to angular and how to implement uploading excel files. I tried to follow a tutorial on how to do it below but i get an error

> self.context.onChange is not a function

in my country_table component. I don't know if my approach is right.

**FileUploadComponent**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'file',
    templateUrl: '../Country/country_table.html',
    providers: [ FileUploadService ]
})
export class FileUploadComponent {
    constructor(private service:FileUploadService) {
        this.service.progress$.subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log('progress = '+data);
            });
    }

    onChange(event) {
        console.log('onChange');
        var files = event.srcElement.files;
        console.log(files);
        this.service.makeFileRequest('http://localhost:9000/upload/country', [], files).subscribe(() => {
            console.log('sent');
        });
    }
}
```

**FileUploadService**

```
@Injectable()
export class FileUploadService {
   public progress$;
   public progressObserver;
   public progress : number;
   constructor () {
        this.progress$ = Observable.create(observer => {
            this.progressObserver = observer
        }).share();
   }

   makeFileRequest (url: string, params: string[], files: File[]) {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
                xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
            }

            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                        observer.complete();
                    } else {
                        observer.error(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            };

            xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
                this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

                this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
            };

            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.send(formData);
        });
    }
}
```

**country_table.html**

Comment: Can you post your `country_table.html`. The problem seems toe be there

Comment: @PierreDuc   country_table.html is on the question, please and i get the error, when i upload the file

Comment: there is no issue with your code as far as I can see. Could you be using that `country_table.html` in another component??

Comment: @PierreDuc Actually, the country_table.html is a file which has it's own component in one directory. The File Upload service and File service component are also in another directory. But i don't understand why the country_table.html doesn't see the function onChange because the fileUploadComponent points to the country_table. html

Comment: Because you do not use the `<file></file>` tag, but probably the tag from the other component

Comment: @PierreDuc i don't get the above statement, sorry

Comment: Can you show the template where you use the `FileUploadComponent`? This component has as selector `file`, which means you got to have a `<file></file>` somewhere in your application

Comment: @PierreDuc, I just edited it to have the <file></file> tags in the country_table.html but i get another error raised Error: Error in ./FileUploadComponent class FileUploadComponent - inline template:2:24 caused by: event.srcElement is undefined.. I have updated it in the question

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the tag defined inside your component. So in this instance

```
`<file></file>`
```

On the other hand, to get the files from the event you have to use `event.target`:

```
var files = event.target.files;
```

Comment: thank you very much. i also realized that mozilla doesn't allow srcElement.files; but google chrome does.